# Clarification required on how Camel Quartz works

Tags: apache-camel

I have a simple question that I can't find information on regarding Apache Camel-Quartz. For Camel-Quartz to work do you have to deploy inside a web container like Tomcat? And hence because the application will always be alive it will know when to run?

I'm asking because if you deploy your Camel application in a stand alone JVM I don't see how the application will be smart enough to understand when to run.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is embedded with your Camel application and thus when you start Camel, quartz is also started. And then it knows when to run, as long you keep the Camel application running.

There is no magic in there. Its just java code that runs, and Quartz is also just java code. And it does not require a special server etc. Quartz is just a library (some JAR files) that you run together with your own application.

Quartz just have logic for scheduling jobs (eg its like a big clock-work) that knows what the time is, and when to trigger jobs accordingly to how you tell it to.